# Analysis of accuracy data in R with 4 possible answer choices

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I am working on my Master's thesis in linguistics where I employ a picture selection task as a secondary (comprehension) task within a self-paced-reading online experiment. Participants have the choice of selecting 1 of 4 available pictures (there is 1 correct target that matches a previous sentence, 1 competitor that is somewhat similar to the target but not really an accurate choice and 2 competitors that are completely unrelated and would yield an obvious incorrect answer). I am using this accuracy measurement in an exploratory manner and I am not sure what statistical method would be the best fit in this case. From what I have read, using logistic regression (generalized linear model) seems to be recommended, but I am not sure this is the way to go. Just to recap: a target selection would be an obvious correct choice, a competitor selection would not exactly be inaccurate, but informative that participants ignore the depicted difference between the target and the competitor, while the distractors can be thought to be a completely inaccurate response.

I would be very, very grateful for your advice. It is important to me to use an accurate way of analyzing things and since I do not have much experience with statistics, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! purely statistics questions (not related with coding) fit better CrossValidated. What exacly do you want to model? Which selection the competitor choose based on his characteristics?

Comment: The purpose of statistical analysis is to answer your research questions but, so far, you haven't articulated any questions. What is that you want to learn from the data? Statistics isn't a mindless method of just "analyzing things". Statistical analysis is always directed towards learning something specific. So have a think about what you are trying to learn and try to articulate it. This process of formulating questions is, by the way, one of the key skills that a research project like this is intended to teach you.

Comment: @GordonSmyth thank you for your comment. I agree with you on this completely. I cannot disclose the research question due to the lab regulations. The accuracy measure that I am planning to use is exploratory. The phenomenon that I am looking at has not been researched before and I do not know what to expect. The differences in the relevant pictures (1 target - fully matching, 1 competitor - relevant, but not a perfect match) are small, but participants' choices will inform on the subjects' ability to differentiate between depictions of a concept.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough reputation to comment and would still like to try and help out!

Without looking into your data, it is quite hard to properly specify a correct statistical model for you.

Is it possible to give us some more insight into your data?

- What will be the response/outcome/dependent variable?
- What will be the explanatory/independent variable?
- Are there any other covariates present? (For example multiple questions)
- Is there any form of clustering present?

Furthermore, as Wimpel suggested in the comments, your question would probably be more suited for stats.stackexchange.com. Unless you want to go towards fitting it in R with code.

Thanks!